# location.reload(true); not working in ie11

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

i have a script that reload the page when the value is >= 100 the problem is that location.reload(true); are not working in ie11, i also have tried with window.location = self.location.href; but i am having the same problem, in other browsers it works good.

```
$(function () {
if (value < 100) {
    var timer = setInterval(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: $("#ancUrl").attr('href'),
            data: {},
            success: function (msg) {
                console.log("This is msg:" + msg);
                var msgInt = parseInt(msg);
                if (msgInt > value)
                    value = msgInt;
            },
            error: function (err) {
                console.log(err.responseText);
            },
            dataType: "json"
        });
        $("#progress-bar").width(value.toString() + "%");

        if (value >= 100) {
            clearInterval(timer);
            window.location = self.location.href;
        }
    }, 2000);
}
```

});

Comment: try `window.location.href = window.location.href;`

Answer (score 0):

You don't appear to have defined `self` anywhere, so you may have an error there. Beyond that, you're trying to assign the value of `href` as the whole value of `location` - which is meant to be an object. Instead, try:

```js
window.location.href = window.location.href;
```

Answer (score 0):

place the if in the success function, ajax is asynchronous the if will execute immediately but value will change after the ajax has completed so the code may never reach the if statement

```
$(function () {
if (value < 100) {
    var timer = setInterval(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: $("#ancUrl").attr('href'),
            data: {},
            success: function (msg) {
                console.log("This is msg:" + msg);
                var msgInt = parseInt(msg);
                if (msgInt > value) {
                    value = msgInt;
                    $("#progress-bar").width(value.toString() + "%");
                    if (value >= 100) {
                       clearInterval(timer);
                       location.reload(true);
                     }
                }
            },
            error: function (err) {
                console.log(err.responseText);
            },
            dataType: "json"
        });



    }, 2000);
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to move the if statement into the success callback.

Like that you can clear the interval into the same stack and reload the page on the good 
.

```
$(function() {
  if (value < 100) {
    var timer = setInterval(function() {
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: $("#ancUrl").attr('href'),
        data: {},
        success: function(msg) {
          console.log("This is msg:" + msg);
          var msgInt = parseInt(msg);
          if (msgInt > value)
            value = msgInt;
          $("#progress-bar").width(value.toString() + "%");
          if (value >= 100) {
            clearInterval(timer);
            window.location = self.location.href;
          }
        },
        error: function(err) {
          clearInterval(timer);
          console.log(err.responseText);
        },
        dataType: "json"
      });

    }, 2000);
  }
});
```